# Pointing 3 domains to same Django app and using different urls to serve each

Tags: python, django, nginx

So I have three domains and three subdirectories in my django app.

lets say my IP is x.x.x.x

I want the app to work like this:

```
url_visited_by_the_user
content_served_from

www.domain1.com/
x.x.x.x/dir1/

www.domain1.com/bla/bla/
x.x.x.x/dir1/bla/bla/

www.domain2.com/
x.x.x.x/dir2/

www.domain2.com/bla/bla/
x.x.x.x/dir2/bla/bla/

www.domain3.com/
x.x.x.x/dir3/

www.domain3.com/bla/bla/
x.x.x.x/dir3/bla/bla/
```

I dont want the user to see dir1, dir2, etc.
I am using Nginx. Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: This is a webserver configuration problem and not related to programming. You should ask this on Server Fault.

Comment: Asked http://serverfault.com/questions/774247/pointing-3-domains-to-same-django-app-and-using-different-urls-to-serve-each